# run bottle app on my server

Tags: python, bottle

I program my app with python Bottle in my pc. I run my app with `run(host='localhost', port = 80)`
I want to run app on my ubuntu VPS that installed **virtualmin** on it. how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

The command should be

```
run(host='mydomain.com' port=80)
```

Sometimes **port 80** is busy and you can't use it, so change the port to another (like **8080** or **1080**) to run your app.